# How to properly use setTimeout with javascript when debugging in web browser

Tags: javascript, debugging

```
javascript:var load = setTimeout(function() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('accept');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
//code
}
}, 5000);
```

When executing the script, it looks to execute without waiting 5 seconds.I would like it to only execute the code one every 5 seconds to check to see if the system can recognize a bot using the same time

Comment: Assuming the `javascript:` part is just weirdness, the code posted works just fine, and waits for five seconds. There must be parts you're not showing us.

Comment: Could you make that into a runnable example? Maybe put it on jsfiddle.

Comment: The code is a full working example all but the code in the for loop to cut down on size. Basically, all I do is run the javascript: in a debug console on google chrome to execute it in the browser. however, it appears to click the buttons instantly and not wait 5 seconds to go on to the next one

Comment: We need more information to help you out.... But I would suggest using console.log and printing stuff if that's all you can give us.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy-pasting this into your Chrome dev console:

```
function iterate (i, n) {
    if (i == n) {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(function(i, n) {
        return function () {
            /* insert code here
             * i.e.: console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('accept')[i]);
             */
            iterate(++i, n);
        };
    }(i, n), 5000);
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('accept');
var inputsLen = document.getElementsByClassName('accept').length;
iterate(0, inputsLen);
```